# is my pandas index datetime dtype or an object dtype

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the following `df`:

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
d = {'.KS200': {datetime.date(2016, 10, 3): 10, datetime.date(2016, 10, 4): 259.18, datetime.date(2016, 10, 5): 258.99, datetime.date(2016, 10, 6): 261.13, datetime.date(2016, 10, 7): 260.06}, '0001.HK': {datetime.date(2016, 10, 3): 99.45, datetime.date(2016, 10, 4): 99.45, datetime.date(2016, 10, 5): 99.25, datetime.date(2016, 10, 6): 98.7, datetime.date(2016, 10, 7): 98.0}}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d)
```

This dataframe should have at it's index `datetime` as `dtype` but if I print:

```
print(df.index)
Index([2016-10-03, 2016-10-04, 2016-10-05, 2016-10-06, 2016-10-07], dtype='object')
```

I get `object`. What is going on here ?

Comment: FYI, if you replace `datetime.date` by `datetime.datetime`, you get the expected index type

Answer (score 0):

Your index items type is `datetime.date`

Lets check:

```
type(list(df.index)[0])
```

gives

```
datetime.date
```